# Unusual behaviors of PlanarFaceList

Tags: graphs-and-networks

To describe this question clearly, we have to provide some strict definitions regarding planar (plane) graphs.

First, we consider connected graphs.

> A **plane graph** is a particular drawing of a planar graph in the
> Euclidean plane. Let $G$ be a connected plane graph. **Faces** of $G$
> are open 2-cells. The boundary of a face $f$ is the **boundary** in
> the usual topological sense. It is a collection of all edges and
> vertices contained in the closure of $f$ that can be organized into a
> closed walk in $G$ traversing along a simple closed curve lying just
> inside the face $f$. This closed walk is unique up to the choice of
> initial vertex and direction, and is called the **boundary walk** of the
> face $f$.

In Mathematica 13.2，

```
g1 = Graph[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {1, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 1}}, 
  VertexLabels -> Automatic]
PlanarFaceList[g1]
```

[image]
Out:

```
{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 4, 5}, {2, 1, 4, 5, 1, 3}, {4, 1, 5}}
```

But if we set `GraphLayout -> "PlanarEmbedding"`, some strange things are happening

```
g = Graph[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {1, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 1}}, 
  GraphLayout -> "PlanarEmbedding", VertexLabels -> Automatic]
PlanarFaceList[g]
```

Out:

```
{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 4, 5}, {2, 1, 3}, {4, 1, 5}}
```

[image]

Note that the exterior face of g in the embedding  should be {1,2,3,1,4,5}.

But the above output is strange. Who represents the exterior face? **IGFaces** in backpack **IGraphM** seems ok.

If a graph is not connected, is there a better way to describe the set of faces.

```
g = Graph[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {6, 4}}, 
  VertexLabels -> Automatic]
PlanarFaceList[g]
```

Out:
{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {2, 1, 3}, {5, 4, 6}}

The exterior face may be considered a group: {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}

[image]

Comment: I am not at all sure what your question is here. Could you spell it out more clearly and explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: @MarcoB I just made some modifications. Once the planar embedding of a planar graph is given, each face can be represented by a walk along its boundary. Some vertices will be traversed twice or more in the walk.

Comment: It is odd that when I specify the graph embedding, Mathematica's results do not accurately reflect the external faces. When the graph is 2-connected and each face's boundary forms a simple cycle, PlanarFaceList should not encounter any issues.